# What is it called when a key in a key value pair loses it's meaning?

Tags: theory, key-value

Let's say I have a feed of data in the form of key-value pairs. This feed comes from multiple sources which provide additional fields and also reuse similar fields to mean different things.

An issue occurs when you try to extract meaning from a data set made from both sources using these similar fields.

What is this phenomenon called?

Example from source `A`:

{ name: 'building A', ... }

Example from source `A-firewall-events`

{ name: 'rejected', ip: '...', ... }

Comment: Your example doesn't provide any sort of 'phenomena' or 'loss of meaning.' using 'name' as a key in both data sets is simply a bad design decision if you have no other context from which to decipher what the data belongs to. (IE Building.name, FirewallEvent.name). I would call this 'phenomena' bad planning.

Comment: @jjhavokk Its called exaggeration, thats a statement that represents something as better or worse than it really is. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The key, `name`, has no semantic association outside of its context, which in your example is `A` and `A-firewall-events`. There is no loss of data or loss of meaning. Unless you append the source of the key value `name` will not have any inherent meaning. There exists no terminology to describe this, as it is solely the result of poor software engineering practices.